# Damped Linear harmonic oscillator , energy question

Tags: classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

The general trajectory of a one-dimensional simple harmonic oscillator for Fspr = −kz can be expressed as
z(t) = A cos(ω0t + δ) ,
where ω0 =  k/m is the angular frequency and the constants, A and δ,
are determined by the initial conditions.
If we add a small drag force, Fr = −γz ̇, the amplitude of the oscillation, A, will obviously decrease. Thus, a reasonable ansatz (i.e., educated guess) for the trajectory is $$z(t) = A(1 + βf(t)) \cos(ω_0t + δ)$$ ,
where f(t) is a function of time satisfying the initial condition, f(0) = 0.

So part 1 was to find f(t) such that that function satisfies the equation of motion, to the first order B = $\gamma$/2m. I did that and found that f(t) = -t, which i know is right.

So now the function is $$z(t) = A(1 - βt) \cos(ω_0t + δ)$$, and I was tasked with finding the total energy 
$$E = \frac{m}{2}z'^2+\frac{k}{2}z^2 = \frac{m}{2}[z^2+w_o^2z'^2]$$
and the work done by drag $$ W_r = \int_0^tF_rz'dt = \int_0^t(-\gamma z')z'dt$$ and then show how the two are related.

When i solve for the energy i get 
$$E = A^2mw_o[\frac{w_o}{2} - w_0Bt - B\sin(w_0t + \delta)\cos(w_0t+\delta)]$$
and when i solve for the work done i get 
$$ W_r =A^2mw_o[- w_0Bt - B\sin(w_0t + \delta)\cos(w_0t+\delta) +B\sin(2\delta)] $$

but I think E + $W_r$ should equal to $\frac{1}{2}kA^2 = \frac{1}{2}A^2mw_o^2$, since that would be the total energy in the system at the beginning (potential at max extension), which means one of the equations is wrong...

Comment: For large $t$ $$z(t) = A(1 - βt) \cos(ω_0t + δ)$$ does not look right.

Comment: its supposed to be from perturbation theory to first order in B. Its not the real solution. But i know that part is right

Comment: I haven't done the math, but it doesn't seem that $W$ should be proportional to $B$. $W$ should equal the (nonzero) undamped value when $B=0$.

Comment: but W is the work done by the damping, and B is gamma/2m which is the damping coefficient. How can they not be related?

Comment: I think I see what you're doing. Could it be because it is not at max extension at the beginning due to the phase $\delta$ ?